# Kotlin extensions throws NullPointerException in Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin-android-extensions

- This issue does not occur on my test devices, ranging from Android 6 - Android 10.
- This issue occurs on the client's test phone, Samsung Galaxy S20 Ultra 5G.
- Tried myself on a Samsung Galaxy S20 Ultra 5G, couldn't reproduce.
- The issue is seen in Firebase Crashlytics, but so far cannot be reproduced.

  ```
  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


  import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
  import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
  }

  private fun initializeViewPager(list: List<MyObject>) {
     adapter = TabFragmentAdapter(supportFragmentManager, fragments!!)
     val vp: ViewPager = list_container.viewPager // crash
     vp.adapter = adapter
  }

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/backgroundimagenew"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

      </LinearLayout>
  </layout>
  ```

**Crash in crashlytics:**

```
nl.companyname.android.ui.activities.MainActivity.initializeViewPager (MainActivity.kt:356)
nl.companyname.android.ui.activities.MainActivity.onLoadFinished (MainActivity.kt:335)
nl.companyname.android.ui.activities.MainActivity.onLoadFinished (MainActivity.kt:68)
androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderObserver.onChanged (LoaderManagerImpl.java:250)
androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify (LiveData.java:131)
androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue (LiveData.java:149)
androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue (LiveData.java:307)
androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue (MutableLiveData.java:50)
androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.setValue (LoaderManagerImpl.java:189)
androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete (LoaderManagerImpl.java:174)
androidx.loader.content.Loader.deliverResult (Loader.java:132)
androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete (AsyncTaskLoader.java:258)
androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute (AsyncTaskLoader.java:83)
androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask.finish (ModernAsyncTask.java:490)
androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage (ModernAsyncTask.java:507)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8154)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:496)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```